# Selenium WebDriver Java issue with drop down menu

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, safari, automation

I am new to selenium webdriver and I am trying to automate drop down menus but nothing is happening. I tried selectByVisibleText and selectByValue but got the same results. I am using Safari Driver on a mac in Eclipse Java. Below is a piece of the code I've written.

```
driver.findElement(By.name("firstName")).sendKeys("automationFName");      
driver.findElement(By.name("lastName")).sendKeys("automationLName");
driver.findElement(By.id("email")).sendKeys("automate" +        
rand.nextInt() +"@automatetest.com");
driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("aaaaaa");
Select dropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("month"))); //Not working
dropdown.selectByVisibleText("May"); //Not working
driver.findElement(By.name("zip")).sendKeys("90210");
driver.findElement(By.id("signUpButton")).click();
Thread.sleep(2000);
driver.close();
```

Below is the website code.

```
<select data-corners="false" id="month" name="month" title="Birthday">
            <option value="">Month</option>
                                <option value="1">Jan</option>
                                <option value="2">Feb</option>
                                <option value="3">Mar</option>
                                <option value="4">April</option>
                                <option value="5">May</option>
                                <option value="6">June</option>
                                <option value="7">July</option>
                                <option value="8">Aug</option>
                                <option value="9">Sept</option>
                                <option value="10">Oct</option>
                                <option value="11">Nov</option>
                                <option value="12">Dec</option>
                        </select>
```

Thanks

Edit:

I'm not getting any errors. Just a warning. `org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select is never used` but the import is there and Eclipse isn't flagging it.

Comment: And what is the error? What is the behaviour?

Comment: Is `dropdown == null`?

Comment: Im not getting any errors. Just a warning. "org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select is never used" but the import is there and Eclipse isn't flagging it. 'import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;'

Comment: Its a Safari issue. Tried with Chrome and worked like a charm.

Comment: Perhaps you have an additional `Select` class imported from another library? I see that you definitely use this class in your code but the warning still there.

Answer (score 0):

First, create a webelement containing the cssselector (or any locator) of those options. Next, create a List of the previous element and locating the options by their common locator. Eg -

```
WebElement optionslist = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("locator"));
List<WebElement> optionslist2 = optionslist.findElements(By.tagName("li"));
```